# CakePhp: Dont load some related tables

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, autocomplete

I've one model, which has several(6) linked tables.

Most of times, I use this model to display one data and I need all those data, but once, to provide data for an auto-complete field, I only need to have 2 tables linked to make my search. This request needs to be very fast because of the autocomplete and the very frequent usage of this request,

I know that I can disable the load of all items(with recursive =0), but not only disable(or enable) some relations.

So how can I do this with cakePhp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use the [Containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) with each of the models that you want to limit.

Then you can use, for example:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('contain' => 'Tag'));
```

To return all posts, alongside related tags, without any other related models being returned.